# My Eclipse E4 plugins only works with new workspaces, workbench.xmi not updating

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

When I create and export my E4 plugins to install in eclipse, my modifications don't show up at first.

I can only see my modifications in workspaces I create after I installed the plugin.

To see my modifications in **old worksapaces, I have to manually delete workbench.xmi file** (.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi).

It does not matter if I export to "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" (copying to plugin folder) or "Deployable features" (installing it), it works all the same related to the workbench.xmi file issue.
I tried it with Eclipse Neon and Eclipse Oxygen last version.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong, if that is a knowing issue or the way it suppose to be.

I presume I am doing something wrong.
I would like a way to develop E4 plugins, without having to tell my final user to manually delete the workbench.xmi in their old workspaces, to be able to use it.
Or each time they install an update or new plugins I release.

I am new with E4 plugins development, thanks for any help!!!

Comment: If you are contributing to existing 3.x style perspectives you will have to do a Reset Perspective.

Comment: Thanks greg-449! But I am afraid that happens with menu contribuitions as well.

Comment: You could try to set the _clearPersistedState_ startup option in the product configuration. This will reset the workbench.xmi, but it also means it will be reset on every launch.

Comment: Thank you Modus Tollens! 
I am new with plugin development and I never tried to create a product configuration file before. After a lot of research and tryings, I am not sure I fully understand it. 
It seems a product it is a set of plugins, features and/or configurations for an eclipse instance or RCP, if I got this right. Not exactly a plugin like you provide in "Install New Software..." to your eclipse, that is what I want to: provide a plugin.

Comment: But clearPersistedState (as you said) could be a solution. In another forum I got a suggestion to set clearPersistedState=true in config.ini, it is not exactly what I want to but I will use that for now.

Comment: After more tests I realised that both, delete workbench.xmi file and set clearPersistedState=true in your config.ini, produce undesired effects. 

Reset screen postion, reset perspectives, views and don't keep opened files.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the other forum I asked it: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089590/

In the 
**plugin.xml** file -> **Extensions** tab -> **org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model** extension -> (fragment)

Set **apply to always**, in my new plugin projects **apply was set to initial by default**.